# Add array to memcache

Tags: php, memcached

Here is my code to "store" mysql queries with memcache

```
$mem = new Memcache;
$mem->connect('127.0.0.1', 11211);

$query = "SELECT * FROM tbl limit 0,20 ";
$key = md5($query);

$get_data = $memcache->get($key);

if($get_data) {
 echo 'Data Pulled From Cache';
} else {
   $res = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
   $memcache->set($key, $res, TRUE, 3600); 
}
```

The problem is that memcache store only the first row returned by query. 
How to save all 20 rows within one key in memcache ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
$res = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$memcache->set($key, $res, TRUE, 3600);
```

use `mysql_fetch_array()` with `while`, [check this](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: would you mind elaborating the example? i am having a lot of trouble here.. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/14014953

Answer (score 7):

The statement

$res = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query);

only fetches ONE row from the query result.

Try something like this to fetch the entire result before storing it in the cache:

```
$res = array();
$qres = mysql_query($query);
while($a = mysql_fetch_array($qres, MYSQL_ASSOC))
  $res[] = $a;
mysql_free_result($res);

$memcache->set($key, $res, TRUE, 3600);
```